# Lat long shows 0,0 co-ordinates in micromax phone android

Tags: android

I am fetching current location , i can get in all phone just not in micromax phone any idea ?

Best Regards.

Comment: Is there any error, Check in logcat. And put here your logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Check weather your Location providers are enabled or not in Phone Settings.
In code first check for permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Also check the LocationChanged event handler

```
try{
            locListener = new LocationListener() 
            {           
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {                           
                }

                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {                            
                }

                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {                           
                }

                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {  
                    deviceLoc = location;
                    nOrgLatitude = deviceLoc.getLatitude();                 nOrgLongitude = deviceLoc.getLongitude();
                    locManager.removeUpdates(this);
            }};

            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locListener);
            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locListener);
```

As shown you can request location from GPS_Provider or Network_Provider. Also go through the Geocoder documentation that provides many location based functionality. As @hemant mentioned keep a close watch on logcat.